# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined with mongodb nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

I am trying to run jest test cases but I am facing error -

> ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined .

Node version -14.18.0.

[Mongodb NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) - 4.1.3 .

Typescript version - 4.4.3.

Below is my test code --

```
beforeAll(() => {
  connection = new Connection();
});
```

Below is my connection class code

```
import { MongoClient, Db, MongoClientOptions } from 'mongodb';

class MongoConnection {
  
public async conn(){
    await MongoClient.connect('', options);
}
}
```

Error --

> FAIL  connection.test.ts

● Test suite failed to run

> ```
> ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
>
>   
> > 1 | import { MongoClient, Db, MongoClientOptions } from 'mongodb';
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the problem got solved.

I have added at the top --

```
global.TextEncoder = require("util").TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = require("util").TextDecoder;
```

Not sure why the error was showing.

Comment: Where to add this? At the top of which file??

Comment: @dragonfly02  I was facing the problem while executing test cases . So I have added in the test case file at the top .

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete answer:

When the newer packages of mongodb get installed (at leats with v4.11.0) it has the `mongodb-connection-string-url` package as a dependency and that in turn, has the `whatwg-url` package as a dependeny.

It seems the `whatwg-url` package is missing a line at the top of the `encoding.js` file in `node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js`.

The line to be added is:

```
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util'); //this line needs to be added
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8", { ignoreBOM: true });

...
```

This solves the problem, but if the node modules are deleted and installed again, the same problem will reappear, which is not ideal. Would like to know if there is a better alternative then to manually adjust this file...

Answer (score 0):

Using Jest, if you don't have a "Jest" configuration in your package.json, for me it appeared to be defaulting the "testEnvironment" to "jsdom" which was mutating the global object removing TextEncoder.

This was on Node v18 tested by logging out process.version, check you are running a version above 12 I believe, and that you're not running a different version of node installed on system from nvm.

Placing this in my package.json solved the issue. If you have a testEnvironment of jsdom, then it would need to be "node" instead or polyfilled onto the global object like other answers suggest.

```json
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
  },
```

This was absolute pain to solve hope it helps.